# mimetype file with asp

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a way to get the mimetype of a file by using asp?
If just have the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing this would be to take the file extension of the file and look up the Registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file extension>`. There should be a "Content Type" value under this key that gives the MIME type of the file, at least for the most popular file types.

This assumes the file extension is a reliable indicator of the file's contents. On Unix, there is the [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command which can look for "magic numbers" inside the file and can return the correct file type even if the extension is wrong. A [port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) of this utility exists for Windows. You might be able to [execute it from ASP and capture its output](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html).