# Is it possible to detect file type for images without an extension using VB / Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, mime, fso

I am using a script to pull images from remote URLs, however some don't have any extension.

Is there a way to detect the Mime type using vb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414218/mimetype-file-with-asp

Comment: As stated, I don't have an extension, the question you referenced explains how to find the type using the extension...

Comment: Actually, the question is the same as yours. Yes the only answer in the mentioned question explains about the extension. But this question is still a duplicate. It is only to show you that others have tried, but not succeded. Try maybe putting on a bounty to get more attention to the question and hopefully an answer you can use.

Comment: Can you install a COM? If yes there are a few options.

Answer (score 0):

read few first bytes from files. than match it to pattern, lile:

GIF89 -- for GIF

%PNG -- for PNG